# Classical electromagnetism field strength with index up and down

Tags: electromagnetism, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions, covariance

In Classical electromagnetism, we know the Lagrangian density read
$$
\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}
$$
where
$$
F_{\mu \nu}=\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}-\partial_{\nu}A_{\mu}
$$
However, I am trying to figure out the physical meaning of $F_{\mu}^{\nu}$, because I met an expression like this(Minkowski metric: diag(1 -1 -1 -1))
$$
F^{0 i}F_{i}^{\ 0}=\mathbf{E}^{2}
$$
I know that we usually can identify $E^{i}=-F^{0i}$, but how about $F_{i}^{\ 0}$? Or, more generally, $F^{\ j}_{i}$? How can above equation equal?

Comment: Since there are ones in the Minkowski metric, there is a good chance that objects with switched indiex positions can be equal. Also, $F$ is not symmetric so please introduce spaces to let us know the order of the indices.

Comment: Hi Daren. Welcome to Phys.SE. Which Minkowski signature convention do you use?

Comment: @Qmechanic I used diag(1 -1 -1 -1), as in Peskin's QFT book.

Comment: Indeed, $F_j^{\ \ i} = g_{j\mu} F^{\mu i} = - g_{j\mu} F^{i\mu} = -F^i_{\ \ j}$.